# Неправильная работа if

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, if, print

На данный момент у меня четверг, я сделал код, который считает, какой сегодня день недели и сохраняет его в виде числа. Например четверг - 4.
При проверке значения должно было написать PON, а пишет 4.

```
    import datetime
week = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()
#выводит какой сегодня день недели в цифрах, например Четверг - 4
if week == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7:
    print(week)
else:
    print("PON")
#сегодня четверг и должно выводиться PON, но выводиться 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное так:

```
import datetime
week = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()
#выводит какой сегодня день недели в цифрах, например Четверг - 4
if week in (1,3,5,7):
    print(week)
else:
    print("PON")
```

Либо так:

```
import datetime
week = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()
#выводит какой сегодня день недели в цифрах, например Четверг - 4
if week == 1 or week == 3 or week == 5 or week == 7:
    print(week)
else:
    print("PON")
```

Выбирайте как лучше.